# Variable using GETUTCDATE() does not not work with DATEADD function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Creating mock data and trying to increase record timestamp by 10 senconds for each value however not working just giving me current timestamp for all values

recreate table used

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    sensor_values int,
    recorded_time datetime
    );
```

code

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @RecordedTime DATETIME 
DECLARE @RecordedTimeConstant DATETIME 


SET @RecordedTimeConstant=GETUTCDATE() 
SET @Counter = 1

/* First loop to create mock data for Area temperature*/
/* generating 1000 values between 20 and 25*/
/* Recorded time in 10 second increments*/

WHILE (@Counter <= 1000)
BEGIN
    SET @RecordedTime= DATEADD(SECOND, 10, @RecordedTimeConstant)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable] ([sensor_values],[recorded_time])
    VALUES (RAND()*(25-20)+20,@RecordedTime)
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END

/* Second loop to create mock data for Area humidity sensor readings*/
/* Same timestamps so can match Area temperature and Area humidity readings*/
/* AreaHumidity values generated are between 38 and 42*/

WHILE (@Counter <= 2000)
BEGIN
    SET @RecordedTime= DATEADD(SECOND, 10, @RecordedTimeConstant)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable] ([sensor_values],[recorded_time])
    VALUES (RAND()*(42-38)+38,@RecordedTime)
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `SET @RecordedTime= DATEADD(SECOND, @Counter*10, @RecordedTimeConstant);`

Answer (score 2):

It's working exactly as expected. You get the value of `@RecordedTimeConstant` to be the current UTC time, and then **all** your inserts are that value plus 10 seconds. If you `SELECT` the 2 values of `@RecordedTimeConstant` and `@RecordedTime` you'll see that they are 10 seconds apart. You aren't adding 10 seconds to `@RecordedTime` each time, you're doing the **same** expression each iteration and setting `@RecordedTime` to be `DATEADD(SECOND, 10, @RecordedTimeConstant)`; as `@RecordedTimeConstant`'s value is constant, then so too is that value +10 seconds.

Presumably you want each row to have 10 more seconds added to it, not every row have 10 seconds added to the time at the start of the batch. I would, personally, use a tally (I use `GENERATE_SERIES` here, as I assume you're using the latest version of SQL Server, however, on older versions you can use something like [`fntally`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally)), which you can also use to create multiples of 10. You'll also, however, need to change your method to create a random number, and `RAND` won't be appropriate here:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (sensor_values,
                         recorded_time)
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 5 + 20,
       DATEADD(SECOND,10*GS.Value,GETUTCDATE())
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,1000,1) GS;

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (sensor_values,
                         recorded_time)
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 4 + 38,
       DATEADD(SECOND,10*GS.Value,GETUTCDATE())
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,2000,1) GS;
```

Note that the timer starts again for the second `INSERT` (so the first value will be lower than last value of the first `INSERT`), as I didn't know if you wanted to reset the value or not.

Using a tally avoids the use of a `WHILE` loop, which are known to perform (very) poorly.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pe7VU3Xa)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a revised version of your original SQL that produces the desired 10-second increment on each row.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @RecordedTime DATETIME 
DECLARE @RecordedTimeConstant DATETIME=GETUTCDATE()

SET @Counter = 1

/* First loop to create mock data for Area temperature*/
/* generating 1000 values between 20 and 25*/
/* Recorded time in 10 second increments*/

SET @RecordedTime=@RecordedTimeConstant
WHILE (@Counter <= 1000)
BEGIN
    SET @RecordedTime= DATEADD(SECOND, 10, @RecordedTime)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable] ([sensor_values],[recorded_time])
    VALUES (RAND()*(25-20)+20,@RecordedTime)
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END

/* Second loop to create mock data for Area humidity sensor readings*/
/* Same timestamps so can match Area temperature and Area humidity readings*/
/* AreaHumidity values generated are between 38 and 42*/

SET @RecordedTime=@RecordedTimeConstant
WHILE (@Counter <= 2000)
BEGIN
    SET @RecordedTime= DATEADD(SECOND, 10, @RecordedTime)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable] ([sensor_values],[recorded_time])
    VALUES (RAND()*(42-38)+38,@RecordedTime)
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

Comment: Problem with this  is that I need matching timestamps so the second loop should start from the same utc timestamp as the first loop

Comment: Hamid I revised my answer to do that.